# CSS-File ist not updating any more.. Browser is not taking my changes

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, loading

Im working on my website a few days now and I never had a bug like this because since today my Browser is not talking my new CSS File and is always showing my CSS File from yesterday.

I know you guys are thinking I have to delete the cache but I did this 10 times and it doesnt get better.

So I want to show a picture and it doesnt shows up.

```css
.Kontakt{
 background-image:url(../images/Kontaktbild.jpg);
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
 /*  IPAD   /* background-position-y: -150px; */
}
```

```html
<article class="Kontakt">

<p>Hier kann man mich erreichen</p>

</article>
```

And I dont think that the code is wrong or??

Comment: Try changing something else than background image so you can see is it working.. and remove that ugly IPAD comment.. Use your console to check the actual content of your css file

Comment: @Hardy I tryed to change everything and nothing is working and thats so weird.

Comment: What kind of dev setup you have? Local php server? static files?

Comment: @Hardy I'm running the files on my Filezilla

Comment: Is your website online? If you provide a link it would be easier to solve your problem

Comment: So you are uploading files to server every time? You really should create some local dev environment. NodeJS with express makes this pretty simple.. google for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could also be caching that's happening on the server side. Wordpress does this often, and many web hosts have their own caching.

Another way to bust the cache for yourself and all of your users - to make sure that once you make a change, everyone is seeing the most current version - you can add a 'version' to the URL like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css?v=1.1" />`